# Can someone provide the general function to shift the items from array based on given offset?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to shift the items in array based on given offset. In my current project I need to do this often so I am looking for a common function.

```
$data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

$data = shift($data, 2);

dd($data); //should result into [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]

function shift($data, $offset) {
// general code
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: array_splice() - https://eval.in/885995

Comment: are the keys relevant at all, or just values?

Comment: @Don'tPanic If keys specified explicitly then it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel collection macro to create your own custom functions.

Below is the macro which will support the negative offset as well.

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);

$rotate = $collection->rotate(2);

$rotate->toArray();

// [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]

Collection::macro('rotate', function ($offset) {
    if ($this->isEmpty()) {
        return new static;
    }
    $count = $this->count();
    $offset %= $count;
    if ($offset < 0) {
        $offset += $count;
    }
    return new static($this->slice($offset)->merge($this->take($offset)));
});
```

You can use collection in native PHP as well but below function can be used in native PHP.

```
function array_rotate($array, $shift) {
    $shift %= count($array); 
    if($shift < 0) $shift += count($array);
    return array_merge(array_slice($array, $shift, NULL, true), array_slice($array, 0, $shift, true));
}
```

Both functions will preserve keys if explicitly specified.

Comment: This works pretty well. Thanks a lot. I suppose I have to convert this into core php as well because I need to use this in core php also.

Comment: @amolbhatia Updated the answer for native PHP function

Answer (score 2):

Surely as simply as [shifting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) and pushing in a loop

```
function shift($data, $offset) {
    do {
        $data[] = array_shift($data);
    } while (--$offset > 0);
    return $data;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to work with negative offsets as well,

```
function shift($data, $offset) {
    if ($offset > 0) {
        do {
            $data[] = array_shift($data);
        } while (--$offset > 0);
    } elseif ($offset < 0) {
        do {
            array_unshift($data, array_pop($data));
        } while (++$offset < 0);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: @amolbhatia - That's the negative offset that you didn't mention in your original question?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I should have mentioned that. Still thanks a lot for the answer. Tried up-voting but it doesn't reflect

Comment: @MarkBaker Nice answer. But on another note, your answer won't preserve the keys if specified explicitly.

Comment: OK! I'm just giving up